# Trying to prove Trivial zeros of Zeta using Abel-Plana's formula

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

For a research work I ended up needing to give a proof of Zeta's trivial zeros, in order to do so I tried using the Abel-Plana formula.

$\zeta(s)=\frac{2^{s-1}}{s-1}-2^{s}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(s\cdot \arctan(t))}{(e^{t\pi}+1)(1+t^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}} \,dt \implies \frac{2^{-2k-1}}{-2k-1}=-2^{-2k}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin[2k\cdot  \arctan(t)]}{(e^{t\pi}+1)(1+t^2)^{-k}} \,dt$

In the above equation -2k represents the even negative integer, after some development using the complex form of Sin and Arctan I ended up at the following stalemate.

$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{(1+it)^{2k} - (1-it)^{2k}}{(e^{t\pi}+1)} \,dt = \frac{1}{4k+2}$

My issue here is to give a general form of the integral that can suit any given integer k greater or equal than 1 which would enable me to justify this last equality.

Comment: I think it's a lot easier to use Riemann's functional equation to prove this.

Comment: @projectilemotion I guess that would be too easy, it would make the trivial zeros trivial, indeed. ;-)

Comment: Or you could show that eulerian numbers are symerical at even value's.